# I am hearing my screen

Tags: sound-card

Today I installed sound card drivers of my motherboard (Asus P6T SE), and now I have started hearing the things that are happening on my screen. When I scroll, or change windows, basically cause a redraw on screen, I hear noises kind of resembles each action. And I am not on drugs.

What causes this and how can I fix that?

Comment: Baasically you have cheap and/or badly designed hardware, and it's more common than you might think. There is some complex physics going on in our PC's. Good luck tracking it down!

Answer (score 10):

It isn't your screen causing the noise per se, it is caused from one of the controller chips (for either the PS/2 or USB) having interference with the sound chip.

Some motherboards are very badly shielded and there is just nothing you can do to fix that, all I can really recommend is purchasing a PCI / PCI Express sound card and using that instead.

Comment: Correct answer IMO. I use both a stereo PCI M-Audio soundcard and the ASUS motherboard "HD audio" which I use when watching movies (different set of speakers). Whenever I plug speakers to the onboard audio, activity noises show up instantly. Never found a fix for that (it's alone on IRQ 22 as well). It does seems purely EMI related, and the PCI card is fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably experiencing is feedback and interference on the ground between the motherboard's audio jack and the amplifier for your speakers.  This is not unusual.

It appears your mainboard model supports optical (TOSLINK) S/PDIF for audio.  Using that should eliminate all ground interference with external speakers.

You will need a receiver, amplifier or speaker set that supports it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Perhaps you have got an input on the card enabled. Try disabling all recording devices if they are not already:

   on the tray click speaker and mixer text below volume bar.

   Do you see there any microphone? if so click on the icon and untick listen  to device check box.

   Note: I am thinking that this might be cross-over from the input as it started to happen after installing new drivers.
2. Lay your speaker cable away from your monitor cable.
   As other mentioned this might be cross on the output.
3. Increase volume on your PC. Reduce volume with your speaker knob.

   As sometimes when you reduce volume on the PC the signal on the cable is very weak and easily interferenced.

Answer (score 1):

If the monitor is connected usind a D-SUB cable, try connecting it with a DVI cable. As @WilliamHilsum suggested, it is probably interference. It easily comes up with the analog D-SUB cables, sometimes using a DVI cable fixes those problems (especially when the screen is having distortions because of the interference from an antenna cable... happened to me).

Comment: even the monitor is not connected to power i hear the sounds, that eliminates this option.